# Woocommerce - how to sort sold and HIDDEN products to the end of catalog?

Tags: sorting, woocommerce, hidden

This is my first post here so please be understanding ;)

I have a strage problem with Woocommerce and hidden products (catalog visibility) that are counted in catalog/archive pages but shows as empty spaces: https://ar.neodirect.pl/kategoria-pracy/aatest/
Probably it is caused by WPML and duplicated products in other languages.

By the way, I have deeply described the problem here, but with no effective help:
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/hidden-products-are-counted-in-catalog-and-causes-empty-spaces/

Because I’ve lost any hope to eliminate the hidden products, I am trying a solution that may could help a bit.
**I would like to sort the hidden products to the end of a catalog list.**
But I have **already sorted sold products to the end** of the catalog list.

I am using such a code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_query', 'bbloomer_sort_by_stock_status_then_alpha', 999 );
function bbloomer_sort_by_stock_status_then_alpha( $query ) {
    if ( is_admin() ) return;
    $query->set( 'meta_key', '_stock_status' );
    $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'meta_value' => 'ASC', 'date' => 'DESC' ) );
}
```

So, is it possible to rebuild the code and add also hidden products sorting DESC (to the end of the list)?

Thanks in advance for help,
Domin